# Two data series, graph lines are not connected :(

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

When I display a graph with one dataset, line-graph is nice and pretty.
When I display a graph with 2 datasets, lines are not connected on intersections.

```
2021-03-02 19:44:08.000,1,
2021-03-02 19:44:09.000,2,9
2021-03-02 19:44:10.000,3,
2021-03-02 19:44:11.000,,5
2021-03-02 19:44:12.000,,7
```

Nice line-graph, points are not above each other:
[image: nice line-graph, points are not above each other]

I moved first green point to the left, connection with second green point lost:
[image: I moved first green point to the left]

I have newest dygraph 2.1.0.
Tried on Firefox 75.0 (64-bit) and Chrome 80.0.3987.87

Does anybody have an idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried [`connectSeparatedPoints`](https://dygraphs.com/options.html#connectSeparatedPoints)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is connectSeparatedPoints